# Hyperbolic Motion in a Central Field

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I have to give a 30 mins lecture this coming Thursday in my classical mechanics class (graduate level in math department, with Arnold as the primary text) and I am really struggling to find any good literature on the subject of the title.

My professor says that Goldstein "should have" material on this subject.... but it just doesn't, what it does have is about 3/4 of a page on hyperbolic motion in the theory of special relativity (not what I was asked to discuss).  I did give a read over "Analytic Methods" by Hand and Finch (an undergrad text) and it $does$ develope some ideas, but it is a bit to shallow and further the style is a bit foreign to me (clearly a text written for physicists).

I really enjoy the style of Arnold's mechanics text, so if anyone could recommend something that would be at that level and possibly of that style that absolutely does have hyperbolic motion in a central field that would be greatly appreciated, also any good papers would be nice as well.

The following paper is a good example of the level of sophistication I would like (and can handle): http://mae.nmsu.edu/~asanyal/Sanyal_res/CDSS100107.pdf unfortunately, it also completely avoids the paticular case of hyperbolic motion.

I thought preparing for this talk would be a trip to the library and a search on Google, but it's turning out much more complicated than that.  Please keep in mind this is my first physics course, thank you.  Apologies if this is an inappropriate place to put this question (if so, please suggest where I can move it to).

Comment: You may get better help on http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By hyperbolic motion, I mean the subject of the following article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory

Comment: Why is there any difference between this and elliptical motion? it's the same math just with different constants..

Comment: I don't see why... after all, this is why I asked.  In fact, I think it's quite different.  For starters, the motion is unbounded yet there is always some force.

Comment: Will Jagy I wasn't asking for help with using Google....  I'm fully aware of the texts that you've mentioned and they don't help.  For example, John Taylor's text does no treatment of the subject I'm discussing, I would also appreciate it if you would consolidate your posts into one rather than six responses, completely inappropriate.  Also a comment like "What are alternative to Goldstein"? is pointless.  I'm not asking for just any text on mechanics, I'm asking for a text that discusses the particular problem; further I frankly don't care if the physics page is closed, so why are you sharing